# How to insert a timestamp with Node-Oracle driver?

Tags: node.js, oracle, express

I have an Oracle DB with a timestamp field in it. What is the correct SQL code to insert a timestamp into this field?

SQL CLASSIC:

```
insert into test (time_of_add_doc) 
   values (to_timestamp('22/12/17 09:00:00','DD/MM/RR HH24:MI:SS');
```

(1) One row Added success !

I want to do this from server NodeJS after connecting to my database (Success)

```
oracledb.getConnection({
    user: 'ctrm',
    password: 'ctrm',
    connectString: "localhost/sig"
  },
  function (err, connection) {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
      return;
    }
    console.log('Connection was successful!'); //Get Connection success





 connection.execute(      


    "INSERT INTO test VALUES (:time_of_add_doc)", {
    time_of_add_doc: ('22/12/17 09:00:00','DD/MM/RR HH24:MI:SS'),
    },
    function (err, result) {
      if (err)
        console.error(err.message);
      else
      console.log("Rows inserted " + result.rowsAffected);
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

Oracle's expecting a date and you seem to be passing an array into a single bind variable. Construct a date in node and then bind that. Ensure that the datatypes on both sides are correct and let the interface between Oracle and node apply the standard translation when required

```
var time_of_add_doc = new Date(2017, 12, 22, 0, 0, 0, 0)

connection.execute(      


    "INSERT INTO test VALUES (:time_of_add_doc)", {
    time_of_add_doc,
    },
    function (err, result) {
      if (err)
        console.error(err.message);
      else
      console.log("Rows inserted " + result.rowsAffected);
  });
```

You have a trailing comma after `time_of_add_doc: ('22/12/17 09:00:00','DD/MM/RR HH24:MI:SS'),`. I've left it in, but it seems very strange. I can't test to ensure that this is correct at the moment

Comment: Thank's a lot ! Work's

Comment: No problem @Anis; I'm glad! Do you require the trailing comma? I've never really used JS. If this has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.